# Overlapping dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to embed a dropdown div in a wrapper div that has 0 height, so that it takes no space whether or not it is shown, and when it is shown, it overlays the contents placed below. Suppose that dropdown element is a div with content `Foo`. I did something like:

#### HTML

```
<div class="dropdown_wrapper">
  <div id="dropdown_content">Foo</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.dropdown_wrapper{
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

And through Javascript, I switched the `#dropdown_content`'s style between `display: block` and `display: none`. When it is the former, I expect the content to be shown, but it is actually not shown, hidden within the wrapper div that has 0 height.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: When you make the display change, change the height to auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably do not want the wrapper to use any space in the document. to use it as an anchor point use

```
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
```

on the wrapper. this way the content will set it's own bounding box.

the rest seems to work as you intended. check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yx3dt3bb/1/)